# Show sheet when the main window first loads

Tags: macos, swift4, xcode9.2

I am trying to get a sheet to load when the main window first loads.
This sheet is so that it asks the user for a file so that they are sort of forced to open a file for use in the program when they first start.

I tried to put performSegue(withIdentifier: sender:) in viewDidLoad(), however it just loads the sheet and nothing else.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    performSegue(withIdentifier: NSStoryboardSegue.Identifier(rawValue: "browse"), sender: self)
}
```

I want the main window to load, then the sheet to slide down immediately after asking the user to open a file.

Where should I put the performSegue or is there another way I should be doing this?

Comment: I think doing this in `viewDidLoad` is too early. Try to perform the segue after the window is actually on the screen, e.g. in the `windowDidBecomeMain` notification of the `NSWindowDelegate`.

Comment: Because I'm not too familiar with this, does this affect focus? So if I tabbed to a different program will it trigger the segue again?

Comment: Also how would I go about implementing this into code.

Answer (score 0):

@mschmidt is right, I believe; you'll need to perform the segue from `viewDidAppear()` or `windowDidBecomeMain()` or similar; the view needs to have been displayed before you can segue from it.

Note that `viewDidAppear()` will fire when the view is drawn, whether or not it has focus; `windowDidBecomeMain()` will only fire when your app becomes the frontmost app; you may be working in another app but still be able to see your app's windows on-screen, and in this state `windowDidBecomeMain()` may not have fired yet.

And yes, both `viewDidAppear()` and `windowDidBecomeMain()` will fire every time the view appears or the window becomes main, meaning if you minimise the app then un-minimise it, both will fire again. So you'll need some way of ensuring your segue doesn't show again each time, unless you want it to. A simple boolean flag eg `segueHasShown` should achieve that.